# How do I write a PDF file using Java code without importing any third party jars?

Tags: java

How do I write a PDF file using Java code without importing any third party jars?

I am trying to write a plain string into Pdf using java , so i want the java code without using any third part jars

Comment: What you are proposing is impractical.  There is no standard Java SE or EE API for reading / writing PDF files. I guess, if you had a few weeks of spare time you could read the PDF specs, and then write some Java code that did a minimal job.  But frankly ... why waste you time doing it that way?  Use a 3rd-party library.

Comment: I just want a PDF which is having plain string no need of formatted text, image  and all . So for this why i need third part jars i am saying my task is minimal